# Why "Smart cast to kotlin.String" in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, null, kotlin

I wrote my class with nullable argument

```
class MyClass(a: String? = null) {
    var b: String

    init {
        if( a == null ) {
            b = "N/A"
        }
        else {
            b = a
        }
    }
}
```

and noticed, that IntelliJ warns about `b = a` assignment

```
Smart cast to kotlin.String
```

Why is this warning and how to aoid it?

Comment: Others have answered question. Your code is not idiomatic, though. Can remove 'init' all together, and have `val b = a ?: "N/A"`. Note I've made b immutable, but that will depend on it's usage elsewhere in the class

Comment: This is not a warning, warnings are highlighted yellow/orange. A smart cast is (by default) highlighted green.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It’s not a warning, just an information that the compiler knows your variable `a` to be *not* `null`. As a result, it can be used as a `String` instead of nullable `String?` and therefore without safe-operator e.g.

Otherwise, you needed to explicitly cast `a: String?` to `String` in order to make it assignable to the `String` variable `b`, as shown on the following screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This is not something to avoid, this is a language feature called a [smart cast](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts).

The compiler has detected that `a` is a non-null value on a given code path, and therefore it's available to you with a non-nullable `String` type, which lets you use it directly without having to worry about its nullability. If you didn't get a smart cast, you'd have to manually cast it from a `String?` to a `String` to call methods on it - or to assign it to a non-nullable variable, like in your case.

---

Another, perhaps easier example to understand when smart cast kicks in is with subclasses. Let's say you have `Person` and `Customer` classes, with only the latter having a `getPurchases()` method.

In Java, you'd have to do the following to call said method:

```
if (p instanceof Customer) {
    ((Customer)p).getPurchases();
}
```

In Kotlin, you get a smart cast inside the `if` block to the subtype that you've already made the check for:

```
if (p is Customer) {
    p.getPurchases()
}
```

---

If you think about it, the cast from `String?` to `String` is the same mechanism at work - you're getting a smart cast to a more concrete type too.

```
if (a != null)
```

given an `a` of type `String?` is basically the same as

```
if (a is String)
```